# Counting attacks per hour per IP address

Tags: python

I have two files: an `access` file and `auth.log`, which displays information about login attempts.

I am trying to search through the entire document and count the amount of failed password attempts, then display the number of failed attempts per hour per IP address.

It is the per IP address part that I am struggling with. I have code that displays the number of failed attempts per hour but cannot figure out how to display it as per IP address per hour.

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('auth.log') as myAuthlog:
     myAuthlog = (line for line in myAuthlog if "Failed password for" in line)
     for key, group in groupby(myAuthlog, key = lambda x: x[:9]):
        month, day, hour = key[0:3], key[4:6], key[7:9]
        print ("%s:00 %s-%s: %d"%(hour, day, month, len(list(group))))
```

This code currently displays the result as such:

```
08:00  3-Feb: 172
13:00  3-Feb: 4
21:00  3-Feb: 1
08:00  4-Feb: 15
10:00  4-Feb: 60
16:00  4-Feb: 4
07:00  5-Feb: 24
08:00  5-Feb: 86
```

Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

```
Feb  3 08:17:01 j4-be02 CRON[32735]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb  3 08:17:01 j4-be02 CRON[32735]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb  3 08:35:21 j4-be02 sshd[32741]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for reserve.cableplus.com.cn [211.167.103.172] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Feb  3 08:35:21 j4-be02 sshd[32741]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.167.103.172  user=root
Feb  3 08:35:23 j4-be02 sshd[32741]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 34583 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:27 j4-be02 sshd[32744]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for reserve.cableplus.com.cn [211.167.103.172] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Feb  3 08:35:27 j4-be02 sshd[32744]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.167.103.172  user=root
Feb  3 08:35:29 j4-be02 sshd[32744]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 36610 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:32 j4-be02 sshd[32747]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for reserve.cableplus.com.cn [211.167.103.172] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Feb  3 08:35:32 j4-be02 sshd[32747]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.167.103.172  user=root
Feb  3 08:35:35 j4-be02 sshd[32747]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 38355 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:38 j4-be02 sshd[32749]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for reserve.cableplus.com.cn [211.167.103.172] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Feb  3 08:35:38 j4-be02 sshd[32749]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.167.103.172  user=root
Feb  3 08:35:40 j4-be02 sshd[32749]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 40252 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:44 j4-be02 sshd[32751]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for reserve.cableplus.com.cn [211.167.103.172] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Feb  3 08:35:44 j4-be02 sshd[32751]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.167.103.172  user=root
Feb  3 08:35:46 j4-be02 sshd[32751]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 42099 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:50 j4-be02 sshd[32753]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for reserve.cableplus.com.cn [211.167.103.172] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Feb  3 08:35:50 j4-be02 sshd[32753]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.167.103.172  user=root
Feb  3 08:35:52 j4-be02 sshd[32753]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 44102 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:55 j4-be02 sshd[32755]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for reserve.cableplus.com.cn [211.167.103.172] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Feb  3 08:35:55 j4-be02 sshd[32755]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.167.103.172  user=root
Feb  3 08:35:58 j4-be02 sshd[32755]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 45932 ssh2
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post part of your `auth.log` file so that we can test your code. It doesn't have to be the whole thing, just enough lines so that we can test.

Comment: no problem, done

Comment: Is your only problem that you are unable to locate the IP address?

Comment: I'm trying to get it count the failed attempts per ip per hour, my original code counts failed attempts per hour but I dont know how to do it by ip address each hour

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are just the relevant lines that describe attacks, and I've changed the top three to a different IP address so that we can see two different attackers.

```
Feb  3 08:35:23 j4-be02 sshd[32741]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.148 port 34583 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:29 j4-be02 sshd[32744]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.148 port 36610 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:35 j4-be02 sshd[32747]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.148 port 38355 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:40 j4-be02 sshd[32749]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 40252 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:46 j4-be02 sshd[32751]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 42099 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:52 j4-be02 sshd[32753]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 44102 ssh2
Feb  3 08:35:58 j4-be02 sshd[32755]: Failed password for root from 211.167.103.172 port 45932 ssh2
```

Now this code will achieve what you're looking for:

```
from itertools import groupby
import re, json

with open('auth.log') as myAuthlog:
    myAuthlog = (line for line in myAuthlog if "Failed password for" in line)
    attacks = {}
    for key, group in groupby(myAuthlog, key = lambda x: x[:9]):
        group_list = list(group)
        month, day, hour = key[0:3], key[4:6], key[7:9]
        datetime_attacks = f"{hour}:00 {day}-{month}: {len(group_list)}"
        attacks[datetime_attacks] = {}
        for e in group_list:
            ip = re.search(r'Failed password for root from ([\d\.]+?) ', e)
            if ip:
                ip = ip.group(1)
                if ip not in attacks[datetime_attacks]:
                    attacks[datetime_attacks][ip] = 0
                attacks[datetime_attacks][ip] += 1

print(json.dumps(attacks, indent=2, sort_keys=True))

>> {
>>   "08:00  3-Feb: 7": {
>>     "211.167.103.148": 3,
>>     "211.167.103.172": 4
>>   }
>> }
```

Comment: this error comes up     AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group

Comment: different error this time lol     NameError: name 'groupby' is not defined

Comment: my fault accidently deleted when i pasted the code sorry, works now, will look into the code so i understand it more and try a bit of formatingto displayit differently

Comment: @AdrianRowlands Awesome! I'm glad it works. I've also just edited and simplified the Regex line `ip = re.search...` so that it's shorter but still does the same thing.

Comment: @AdrianRowlands The arrows at the top of a post. It's another way to show that you like an answer.

Comment: @AdrianRowlands I've added in a way to pretty-print the resulting dictionary as JSON.

Comment: ok no problem, how do i print each item of the list into a seperate line, i tried looping it with   for x in attacks:
    print(x)   which worked but didnt show the ip addresses

Comment: @AdrianRowlands `for i, e in attacks.items():
    for x, y in e.items():
        print(x, y)`